# Debug error when attempting to run Dart index.html

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am uncertain what the error below represents:

```
GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
  CastApiBootstrap.isExtensionInstalled_    
  CastApiBootstrap.findInstalledExtensionHelper_    
  CastApiBootstrap.findInstalledExtensionWithCallback   
  CastApiBootstrap.findInstalledExtension   
  (anonymous function)  
  (anonymous function)  
GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
  CastApiBootstrap.isExtensionInstalled_    
  CastApiBootstrap.findInstalledExtensionHelper_    
  (anonymous function)  
  xmlhttp.onerror
```

The above is a Debug output when run in WebStorm 11.

The pubServe output is shown below:

```
[web] GET Served 12 assets.
[web] GET packages/polymer_elements/src/web-animations-js/web-animations-next-lite.min.js => polymer_elements|lib/src/web-animations-js/web-animations-next-lite.min.js
[web] GET Served 7 assets.
[web] GET Served 8 assets.
[web] GET Served 7 assets.
[web] GET Served 186 assets.
[web] GET index.dart => Could not find asset epimss_polymer_app|web/index.dart.
[web] GET Served 20 assets.
Build completed successfully
[web] GET Served 12 assets.
[web] GET Served 8 assets.
[web] GET Served 14 assets.
[web] GET Served 228 assets.
```

epimss_polymer_app is my application that is being run.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a problem caused by the outdated Dartium (newer version work in progress) Can you reproduce this message in Chrome?